# Run Functional Tests: Error uploading test run results / attachments

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Environment:

- On-premise TFS 2015 Update 3
- Release Management vNext
- Release definition using tasks:

  - Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment (VS Test Agent 14.0.25420.1)
  - Run Functional Tests (based on a Test Plan)

We have a large test suite of 400+ tests and a custom data collector in place which collects log files of considerable size (50 MB per file is not uncommon). "Run Functional Tests" task seems to execute all tests but fails at the end when trying to publish the test results and attachments:

> W, 3224, 3, 2016/08/24, 02:32:07.663, 322736173808, DTAExecutionHost.exe, Failure attempting to call the restapis. Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: Cannot upload file as it exceeded the maximum file size (104857600 bytes)
>
> *(from DTAExecutionHost.exe.log on the test machine)*

I guess this is a TFS/IIS configuration issue but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Are there any useful or related info in the release definition log? Did you get any error in that log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such configuration in TFS/IIS related to *100M* limitation. According to the error info, this may related to the REST API limitation.

Try to go through your test run attachments to find the file which over 100M then delete it and run the Release definition again to see if the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it has been confirmed here https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2326 that it is a REST API limitation.